# Can I ignore this: Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6' is either not registered in the machine or

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework, provider

I get this error
Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

Can I ignore it? It comes in connection with the edmx File. As I can remember, in VS 2017 there was a designer package for Visual Studio. I am using now VS 2022.